# How to push a nested array of object to another object as a nested array of objects? (MongoDB/NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have a "cart" object that looks like this:

```
  {
        "_id" : ObjectId("cart123"),
        "userId" : "user123",
        "email" : "test@mail.com",
        "products" : [ 
            {
                "productId" : "11111",
                "price" : 20,
                "quantity" : 1
            }, 
            {
                "productId" : "22222",
                "price" : 24,
                "quantity" : 1,
            }
        ]
    }
```

and I have an "order" object that looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("order123"),
    "userId" : "user123",
    "email" : "test@mail.com",
    "products" : [ ],
    "status" : "pending"
}
```

I'm trying to push the contents of the "products" array from the "cart123" to "order123".
I tried using this code:

```
const userProduct = await Cart.find({ userId: userData.userId }).select({ 'products': 1,'_id': 0,  });
const updatedOrder = await Order.findOneAndUpdate({ userId: userData.userId  },
{ $push: { "products": {$each: userProduct }}})
```

but it does not work.

Can anyone please tell me what code I should use?

Comment: Your syntax is overall fine, the only issue is that `Cart.find` returns an array of `cart` objects, just change it to `findOne` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I tried changing it to "findOne" but it still gives me the same error: MongoServerError: The argument to $each in $push must be an array but it was of type: object

Comment: you need to do `userProduct.products` "userProduct" is the cart object.

Answer (score 0):

After playing with the code and suggestion by Tom  (thank you!), the correct code is:

```
const userProduct = await Cart
  .findOne({ userId: userData.userId })
  .select({ 'products': 1,'_id': 0,  });
const updatedOrder = await Order.findOneAndUpdate({
  userId: userData.userId
}, {
  $push: {
    products: {
      $each: userProduct.products
    }
  }
});
```